# Stuck at progressively migrate my website to Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, razor-pages

I chose Vue.js over React and Angular, because it felt much more easier to migrate my existing website (old technologies, ASP.NET Razor Pages inside Visual Studio and no npm) to new technologies.

Everything went great. I changed small portions of my website into Vue applications. For example:

1. Mini cart viewer
2. Comment form
3. Rating
4. Add to cart button
5. Dynamic forms

However, now that I want to show a dynamic form inside a modal dialog, things don't work.

The point is, modal dialog is a Vue application, and the dynamic form is also another Vue application. So, basically what I do is to load a Vue application inside another Vue application.

Here's my code for modal:

```
var modalAppJson = {
    data() {
        return {
            isShown: false
        }
    },
    methods: {
        show: function (data) {
            var _this = this;
            _this.isShown = true;

        },
        hide: function () {
            var _this = this;
            _this.isShown = false;
        }
    }
};
var modalApp = Vue.createApp(modalAppJson);
modalApp.config.globalProperties.app = app;
modalApp.mount('.modalInstance');
```

And here's my code for dynamic form (Vue.js inside Razor Pages):

```
formApp = {
    data() {
        return {
            form: {
            },
            fields: []
        }
    },
    methods: {
        addField(key, value, isValid) {
            var field;
            for (var i = 0; i < this.fields.length; i++) {
                if (this.fields[i].key === key) {
                    field = this.fields[i];
                }
            }
            if (!field) {
                field = { key: key, value: value, isValid: isValid };
                this.fields.push(field);
            }
            field.value = value;
            field.isValid = isValid;
        },
        removeField: function () {

        },
        send() {
            var form = $('#@(Model.Key)Form');
            var loader = $('#@Model.LoaderKey');
            var results = $('#@Model.ResultsKey');
            var submitButton = $('#submit_@Model.Key');
            submitButton.hide();
            loader.show();
            results.text('');
            app.postJson('action=SaveForm&formKey=@Model.Key', JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.form)), function (data) {
                submitButton.show();
                loader.hide();
                results.text('Form is saved successfully');
                results.addClass('success');
                form[0].reset();
            }, function (error) {
                submitButton.show();
                loader.hide();
                results.text(error);
                results.addClass('error');
            });
        }
    },
    computed: {
        isValid: function () {
            var result = true;
            for (var i = 0; i < this.fields.length; i++) {
                if (this.fields[i].isValid === false) {
                    result = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
};
Vue.createApp(formApp).mount('#@(Model.Key)Form');
```

And here's an example of HTML for these two apps:

```
<div class="modalInstance">
    <div>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" @@click="isShown = true">Purchase</a>
    </div>
    <Transition>
        <div v-if="isShown">
            <form novalidate id="@(Model.FormKey)Form" class="formInstance">
                <h1 class="title">@Html.Raw(Model.DatabaseForm.Title)</h1>
                <h3 class="shortDescription">@Html.Raw(Model.DatabaseForm.ShortDescription)</h3>

                @if (hasFieldsRenderer)
                {
                    <partial name="/Pages/Form/@(pascalizedKey)FieldsRenderer.cshtml" model='@Model.Fields' />
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (var field in Model.Fields)
                    {
                        <partial name="/Pages/Fields/@(field.RelatedItems.TypeKey).cshtml" model='field' />
                    }
                }
                <div class="actions">
                    <partial name="@Actions.Save" model='new ActionParameters { Classes="submit button", FormKey=Model.FormKey, Text="Save" }' />
                    <span id="@(Model.FormKey)Loader" style="display: none;">Saving...</span>
                    <span id="@(Model.FormKey)Result"></span>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </Transition>
</div>
```

The top-level `<div>` is controlled by the modal Vue application, and the `<form>` element is controlled by the dynamic form Vue application.

However I see this error when I open the dialog:

> [Vue warn]: Property "form" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.
> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Name')

This works if I show the form in the page and not in a modal. But breaks when I put it inside modal.

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: Why are they different apps? Shouldn't they just be different components in the same app?

Comment: @Salketer, they are different apps, because we are migrating slowly towards Vue.js. Because we can't make our entire website a single Vue.js app. We need to turn each small piece we can into a small Vue.js app.

Comment: I don't see form being accessed anywhere in your code... Are you sure you are showing the correct reproduction code?

Comment: @Salketer, these codes are pieces that are glued together inside a page and then would run in the client side.

Comment: I understand that you are migrating slowly but instead of creating multiple apps, you can create multiple components and then migrate one by one. This will help in reducing some headache and also a best practice to do.

Comment: @RohìtJíndal, you mean I should turn my entire website into a single Vue.js app, and then  for each small part that I want to migrate, I should create a small component? Then what about jQuery that still acts inside this single Vue.js app?

Comment: @AliEXE Yes you understood correctly. for jQuery, you can find out the alternate in vue libraries like vuetify later.